# Removing object from array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

In my application I added one object in array when select cell and unselect and remove object when re-select cell. I used that code but give me error.

```
extension Array {
    func indexOfObject(object : AnyObject) -> NSInteger {
        return (self as NSArray).indexOfObject(object)
    }

    mutating func removeObject(object : AnyObject) {
        for var index = self.indexOfObject(object); index != NSNotFound; index = self.indexOfObject(object) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}

class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    var arrContacts: [Any] = []
    var contacts: [Any] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        arrContacts.removeObject(contacts[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

It gives me 2 error like that:

```
C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3
Value of type '[Any]' has no member 'removeObject'
```

Comment: You can use a `Set<Contact>` rather than an Array.  Can you provide more information about your contact object?  If you have made it yourself you will need it to conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable` in order to put it in a set

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The Swift equivalent to `NSMutableArray`'s `removeObject` is:

```
var array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

if let index = array.firstIndex(of: "beta") {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

**if the objects are unique**. There is no need at all to cast to `NSArray` and use `indexOfObject:`

The API `index(of:` also works but this causes an unnecessary implicit bridge cast to `NSArray`.

Of course you can write an extension of `RangeReplaceableCollection` to emulate the function. But due to value semantics you cannot name it `removeObject`.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element : Equatable {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func remove(_ element : Element) -> Element?
    {
        if let index = firstIndex(of: element) {
            return remove(at: index)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Like `remove(at:` it returns the removed item or `nil` if the array doesn't contain the item.

---

If there are multiple occurrences of the same object use `filter`. However in cases like data source arrays where an index is associated with a particular object `firstIndex(of` is preferable because it's faster than `filter`.

**Update:**

In Swift 4.2+ you can remove one or multiple occurrences of `beta` with [`removeAll(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017530-removeall):

```
array.removeAll{$0 == "beta"}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but it is beyond stupid not to have a remove(object: "beta").

Comment: I think `.index(of: ` is only available if the collection contains `Equatable` types.

Comment: @AdamWaite Yes but this applies also to the Foundation types.

Comment: This isn't right, what if you have more than one "beta"? This only works if the array does not contain more than one occurrences. The right answer is using a filter or running this answer in a while, `while let index = array.index(of: "beta") { array.remove(at: index) }`

Comment: @juancazalla You are right but in the case if the array can contain more than one occurrence use the `filter` solution. But if the objects are unique use always `index(of` because it's much more performant than `filter`

Comment: @vadian I've read that you are a musician too and I was wondering if you could help me out with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349969  . Many thanks

Answer (score 75):

```
var a = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

// Remove/filter item with value 'three'
a = a.filter { $0 != "three" }
```

Comment: That is the correct Swift solution, that makes use of syntax goodies offered by the language.

Comment: What if item is an object?

Comment: @TomSawyer to filter out an object, use $0 !==

Answer (score 26):

For Swift 3, you can use index(where:) and include a closure that does the comparison of an object in the array ($0) with whatever you are looking for.

```
var array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
if let index = array.index(where: {$0 == "beta"}) {
  array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: will this work if I want to remove multiple objects?  like (where: {$0 == "beta" || $0 == "gamma" })

Answer (score 17):

Another nice and useful solution is to create this kind of extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    @discardableResult mutating func remove(object: Element) -> Bool {
        if let index = index(of: object) {
            self.remove(at: index)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    @discardableResult mutating func remove(where predicate: (Array.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        if let index = self.index(where: { (element) -> Bool in
            return predicate(element)
        }) {
            self.remove(at: index)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

In this way, if you have your array with custom objects:

```
let obj1 = MyObject(id: 1)
let obj2 = MyObject(id: 2)
var array: [MyObject] = [obj1, obj2]

array.remove(where: { (obj) -> Bool in
    return obj.id == 1
})
// OR
array.remove(object: obj2)
```

Comment: This only works if the array does not contain more than one occurrences. The right answer is using a filter or running this answer in a while. As a user of this extension, I expect it to remove all the occurrences and not only one

Comment: It's nice, but it should be `remove(element: Element)` because in Array you can store also types like Int, Double - they are not objects.

Answer (score 15):

In **Swift 5**, Use this `Extension`:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable{
    mutating func remove (element: Element) {
        if let i = self.firstIndex(of: element) {
            self.remove(at: i)
        }
    }
}
```

example:

```
var array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
array.remove(element: "beta")
```

---

In **Swift 3**, Use this `Extension`:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable{
    mutating func remove (element: Element) {
        if let i = self.index(of: element) {
            self.remove(at: i)
        }
    }
}
```

example:

```
var array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]
array.remove(element: "beta")
```

Answer (score 6):

1. `for var index = self.indexOfObject(object); index != NSNotFound; index = self.indexOfObject(object)` is for loop in C-style and has been removed
2. Change your code to something like this to remove all similar object if it have looped:

   ```
   let indexes = arrContacts.enumerated().filter { $0.element == contacts[indexPath.row] }.map{ $0.offset }
   for index in indexes.reversed() {
      arrContacts.remove(at: index)
   }
   ```

Comment: enumerated -> filter -> map and remove(at) is smart solution. Recommend this one

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

```
var students = ["Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]

if let index = students.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasPrefix("A") }) {
   students.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct and working one-line solution for deleting a unique object (named "objectToRemove") from an array of these objects (named "array") in Swift 3 is:

```
if let index = array.enumerated().filter( { $0.element === objectToRemove }).map({ $0.offset }).first {
   array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift Remove object from array**

In Swift 3 and Swift 4

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for (index, element) in array.enumerated().reversed() {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

From **Swift 4.2** you can use more advanced approach(faster and memory efficient)

```
array.removeAll(where: { $0 == "c" })
```

instead of

```
array = array.filter { !$0.hasPrefix("c") }
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0197-remove-where.md)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Swift 3

```
array.remove(at: Index)
```

Instead of

```
array.removeAtIndex(index)
```

**Update**

```
"Declaration is only valid at file scope".
```

Make sure the object is in scope. You can give scope "internal", which is default.

`index(of:<Object>)` to work, class should conform to `Equatable`

Answer (score 1):

Extension for array to do it easily and allow chaining for Swift 4.2 and up:

```
public extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    @discardableResult
    public mutating func remove(_ item: Element) -> Array {
        if let index = firstIndex(where: { item == $0 }) {
            remove(at: index)
        }
        return self
    }

    @discardableResult
    public mutating func removeAll(_ item: Element) -> Array {
        removeAll(where: { item == $0 })
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument labels '(where:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat well probably different swift version then ... Oh this question was for 3 ? Well I think I had 4.2 at time of writing but don't remember now, will check it later, it definitely worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This is official answer to find index of specific object, then you can easily remove any object using that index :

```
var students = ["Ben", "Ivy", "Jordell", "Maxime"]
if let i = students.firstIndex(of: "Maxime") {
     // students[i] = "Max"
     students.remove(at: i)
}
print(students)
// Prints ["Ben", "Ivy", "Jordell"]
```

Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used (Swift 5)...

```swift
    extension Array where Element:Equatable
    {
        @discardableResult
        mutating func removeFirst(_ item:Any ) -> Any? {
            for index in 0..<self.count {
                if(item as? Element == self[index]) {
                    return self.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        @discardableResult
        mutating func removeLast(_ item:Any ) -> Any? {
            var index = self.count-1
            while index >= 0 {
                if(item as? Element == self[index]) {
                    return self.remove(at: index)
                }
                index -= 1
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    var arrContacts:[String] = ["A","B","D","C","B","D"]
    var contacts: [Any] = ["B","D"]
    print(arrContacts)
    var index = 1
    arrContacts.removeFirst(contacts[index])
    print(arrContacts)
    index = 0
    arrContacts.removeLast(contacts[index])
    print(arrContacts)
```

Results:

```
   ["A", "B", "D", "C", "B", "D"]
   ["A", "B", "C", "B", "D"]
   ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Important: The array from which you remove items must contain Equatable elements (such as objects, strings, number, etc.)